# Small space between Cooler and GPU - how to secure components

Tags: graphics-card, computer-building, cooling

I'm curious about how to secure my desktop computer setup.

I recently bought an Thermalright Macho CPU Cooler and a Gigabyte 7870 OC Windforce.

http://www.thermalright.com/html/products/cpu_cooler/hr-02_macho_reva.html (Cooler)
http://www.gigabyte.eu/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4368#ov (GPU - Non OC Version)

My Mainboard is an Asus p7.

http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7P55D/ (Mainboard)

My cassis is a lancool dragonlord - theres no space problems there.

However there is only about 5mm from CPU-Cooler-Metal-Plates to graphic card and about 3mm
from fan-cassis-plastic to graphic card. The fan is held in place by a metal wire, which would touch the graphic card if it snaps out (because of the small space I "adjusted" the wire a bit to not exceed the fan-cassis - I don't know how save it is at the moment.)

Unfortunatly I can't but the graphic card in the second slot because its only PCIe 2.0 x4.

Only the first slot under the CPU is PCIe 2.0 16x.

It's possible to run the system (I'm writing now from this computer) but the graphic card is obviously in danger.

I got many questions now (first two because I happened to be in the situation with my "brand-new" graphic card)

**1)** Did I damage the graphic card when starting the computer without having the power connectors connected to the graphic card?

**2)** Did I damage the graphic card when running it in the PCIe 2.0 4x Slot?

**3)** How can I secure the graphic card in this setup? 
I'll put some "duct tape" around the wire but I don't have any more ideas. 
Are there any graphic card chassis that I can but between the cooler and the graphic card?
Any other ideas?

*I really enjoy my new components - they are nearly silent and perform smooth - exchanging them is only the last option*

Answer (score 1):

Your graphics card will not be damaged. Running it in the 4x slot is how you can achieve crossfire on lower end motherboards. Putting some duct tape over the wire so that it doesn't scratch or otherwise damage the card is a good idea. Don't worry you sound like you're on top of it.